# Mixing Angular.js and Bootstrap 3 - where are the incompatibilites?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, events, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is a conceptual question. I am considering adding [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) to my next project, for which I've already elected  using [Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) for UI controls. I see some possible friction in other stackoverflow questions, between the two frameworks, but am not quite sure what is the root reason for possible incompatibilities between the two.

They both listen to events, but bootstrap is mainly a front-end display library, whereas in my view, angular.js goes much deeper. *Perhaps someone can fundamentally explain where the incompatibilities begin to arise*. Hopefully in a way directly lending to determine how much it's a good idea to mix the two in the same project, or what should be avoided if doing so. This would save huge amounts of time learning through debug after it's too late, or avoiding the wrong architecture in the first place.

Comment: I have used the combination successful already using Angular-UI Bootstrap: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. I think the issues have been resolved there by the experts...

Comment: Note that there's an AngularJS version of Bootstrap:  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Also, if someting from Bootstrap is missing in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/, you can simply write an angular directive for it

Comment: The potential problem is that Bootstrap uses jQuery for a lot of its UI functionality. Anything changed by jQuery is not reflected in Angular by itself - for instance checking a checkbox using "regular" javascript (or jquery) will not update its ng-model automatically in the way a user checking it would.

Using the adapted angular version of boostrap as stated above solves these problems.

Comment: @AndersBornholm I think you touch the crux of it. It seems that the answer would be, that given that reason, only the angular bootstrap library (or an equivalent) should be blindly used for 'having' bootstrap and angular work together. If you'd phrase a full answer I'll 'accept it' for the sake of the meta moderator trolls. Should we assume though, that most bootstrap plugins, e.g. [these 50 ](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/07/50-must-have-plugins-for-extending-twitter-bootstrap/), won't work well with angular?

Comment: You can use jQuery plugins with Angular+jQuery, however it can be tricky to integrate them. If you can rewrite the plugins you need to use pure Angular (like Angular-UI does) that will always be ideal. If not, then look at [Angular-Strap](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap) for examples on integrating the plugins "as-is" into Angular.

Comment: @matt: I posted it as an answer first, then thought better of it - so I've just undeleted the answer :-). I'd say most bootstrap plugins can be made into directives, just like Angular-strap have done. But that can be a lot of work. Some common ones (like growl) are also available as stand-alone angular projects on Github.

Comment: @AndersBornholm Care to merge this last one with your answer, I know you tried to clarify something but I'm not sure how they relate (or recall what's been deleted that was now undeleted). Sorry for the annoying 'meta' comment...

Comment: I've tried my best :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The potential problem is that Bootstrap uses jQuery for a lot of its UI functionality. Anything changed by jQuery is not reflected in Angular by itself - for instance checking a checkbox using "regular" javascript (or jquery) will not update its ng-model automatically in the way a user checking it would.

I'd say most bootstrap plugins can be made into directives, just like Angular-strap have done. But that can be a lot of work. Some common ones (like growl) are also available as stand-alone angular projects on Github.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer... unfortunately it means more time fiddling infrastructure integration than building user experience.

Comment: I've tried to overcome the bootstrap.js issues in mobile-angular-ui (http://mobileangularui.com): Instead of attempt to reproduce bootstrap.js behaviour exactly, I basically made two directives communicating each other through events, that are capable to reproduce almost all of the bootstrap.js components interaction. Here is the code: 
https://github.com/mcasimir/mobile-angular-ui/blob/master/src/coffee/directives/toggle.coffee and here the docs: http://mobileangularui.com/#toc6